# Apache camel dynamic routing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel, camel-rest

I have following Apache camel rest service(/sales)  that internally calls another rest service(/getOrders) and get list of objects. Am able to print JSON response in the processor but getting java objects in response while trying from postman. Could anyone pls help me to resolve the issue. Attaching the response log for ref..

```
@Component
public class ApplicationResource extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;

    @BeanInject
    private OrderProcessor processor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").port(9090).host("localhost");

        rest().get("/getOrders").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route().setBody(() -> service.getOrders());


        rest().get("/sales").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route()
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .toD("http://localhost:9090/getOrders?bridgeEndpoint=true").convertBodyTo(String.class).marshal()
                .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Order.class).to("log:foo?showHeaders=true");;
        ;

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some logs in your routes? It would be helpful in debugging.

Comment: pls find the complete RouteBuilder  class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solvedddd !!! i did two things as follows,May be use full for some one
```

1,bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto) - RestBindingMode changes to auto
    from json
2, Added this in the main
    service(/getOrders).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);

```
@Component
public class ApplicationResource extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService service;

    @BeanInject
    private OrderProcessor processor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").port(9090).host("localhost").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        rest().get("/getOrders").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route().setBody(() -> service.getOrders())
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);

        rest().get("/sales").produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).route()
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .toD("http://localhost:9090/getOrders?bridgeEndpoint=true").convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log("body = ${body}");
        ;
        ;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the last .endRest() on "direct:bye" route.
I think you get the rest response before calling your Processor.

Comment: As i specified in the question, am getting the response in processor from camel exchange object but not getting the json response while trying from post man and empty tag is coming

Comment: .endRest() does not mean exchange is over. It means the end of your rest call.

Comment: Removed the same but still not getting json response

Comment: Could you add .to("log:foo?showHeaders=true") before .endRest(); and print the body and headers.

Comment: Thanks.. After i removed ."bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)", the response is coming in post man now but  its coming as list of java objects instead of json. i have modified the question and attached the repose image as you said as reference

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

**First**, I needed to set the `bindingMode` as `RestBindingMode.json` in the `restConfiguration`.

**Secondly**, instead of `marshal()`, you need to use `unmarshal()`.

**Third**, since you are returning a list of orders, `.json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Order.class)` will not be sufficient to unmarshal the list of orders. You need to use a custom format which will be able to unmarshal the list of orders into a json array. This you need to do using `JacksonDataFormat format = new ListJacksonDataFormat(Order.class);`

```
    @Override
    public void configure() {

        JacksonDataFormat format = new ListJacksonDataFormat(Order.class);
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").port(9090).host(localhost).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        rest()
            .get("/getOrders")
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .route()
                .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getMessage().setBody(service.getOrders());
                }})
            .to("log:getOrders?showHeaders=true&showBody=true");

        rest()
            .get("/sales")
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .route()
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .toD("http://localhost:9090/getOrders?bridgeEndpoint=true")
                .unmarshal(format)
                .to("log:sales?showHeaders=true&showBody=true");
    }
```